# Selecting a range based on a where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

With a table like this

```
id | user | message
___________________
0  | dan  | ...
1  | john | ...
2  | dan  | ...
3  | dan  | ...
4  | john | ...
(and so on)
```

How can I select dan's messages from 100 messages before the id to 100 messages after? If I just select based on the id column +/- 100 then there is not guaranteed to be 100 on either side because other users's messages may get in the way. I'd like to `SELECT * from table WHERE user = 'dan' and (some clause here) order by id;`

Database is Postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . . How about `union all`:

```
(select m.*
 from messages m
 where user = 'dan' and id < $id
 order by id desc
 limit 100
) union all
(select m.*
 from messages m
 where user = 'dan' and id > $id
 order by id asc
 limit 100
)
order by id;
```

This should even be reasonably efficient with an index on `(user, id)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you. Should be mentioned though that the order is wrong for the first subquery because it uses order by desc to grab the needed rows but doesn't then reorder them by asc after. Need to throw a `ORDER BY id` on the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER ... something like this

```
Select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (paritition by user order by id) as 'mrnk'
    ,id
    ,user
    ,message
From table
Where user = 'dan'
and mrnk <= 100
```

Or whatever number of Dan's messages you are looking for !

Comment: Sorry ... just noticed the postgresql tag ... this result is a sql server query.  Not sure if same applies to postgresql.

Comment: `row_number()` is present in postgresql as well, FYI